# Побитовый сдвиг в С

Tags: c, битовые-операции, операторы, системы-счисления

Недавно начал изучение С. Естественно, не мог пройти мимо программы для перевода из n-ой системы счисления в x-овую, в данном случае - из двоичной в десятичную. Сам сделал всё вроде бы нормально. Когда посмотрел в интернете, как делают другие, нашёл такой код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
char c;
int result = 0;
while (scanf("%c", &c)) 
{
    if ((c<'0') || (c > '1')) break;
    result <<= 1;
    result += c - '0';
}
printf("%d\n", result);
return 0;
}
```

Посмотрел в интернете про побитовый сдвиг, но всё равно не очень понял, как работает этот код. Понятно всё, кроме двух строк, показанных ниже. Объясните подробнее, как работают эти две строки.

```
result <<= 1;
result += c - '0';
```

Comment: Тоесть тут result <<= 1 происходит удвоение, а потом вычисление при помощи вычитания, правильно?

Comment: Да, удвоение за счёт арифметического сдвига. С помощью вычитания - получается значение "бита 0", хотя бит 0 можно получить и гораздо проще, чаще всего так `c & 1`.  `c - '0'` **не всегда** даёт бит 0, а только в даном примере, поэтому код странноват ( в отличии от  `c & 1` которое всегда даст бит 0). Возможно вы неправильно интерпретировали статью, где кто-то допустил ошибку. Дайте ссылку на статью - тогда больше сможем сказать.

Comment: @nick_n_a Вот сама статья, на stackoverflow https://goo.gl/phQaf6, там тот самый код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас перевод не из "энтовой в иксовую", а конкретно двоичную строку в десятичную.

Просто комментирую код

```
while(scanf("%c", &c))  // Пока считывается в c очередной символ
{
    if ((c<'0') || (c > '1')) break;  // Если это не 0 или 1 - цикл завершается
    result <<= 1;        // Значение result увеличивается в 2 раза (сдвиг влево,
                         // скажем, 011010 становится 0110100. Можно заменить
                         // на result *= 2 или даже result = result + result :)
    result += c - '0';   // Добавление 0 или 1 - если c - символ '0', то понятно что
                         // '0'-'0' даст 0. Точно так же '1'-'0' даст 1
                         // Просто преобразуем СИМВОЛ в ЧИСЛО
}

printf("%d\n", result);  // Вывод result в десятичном (%d) виде
```

Comment: Здесь как раз делается из двоичной в десятичную, не совсем понял почему используется '0' и '1'. Знаю что это из кодировки ANSI и делается для того чтобы не зависит от числового значения, но чего то мне кажется не так я думаю.

Comment: Потому что вы читаете не *число*, а *строку*, которая его содержит, по одному *символу*. Вы, читая очередной символ, читает не 0 или 1, а именно '0' или '1'. А для вычисления их надо перевести в *числовой* формат.

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько видов сдвига влево; это сдвиг с расширением по младшему биту (чётности). Покажу все три сдвига влево.

1. Арифметический сдвиг влево с дополнением нулём. (обычно просто «арифметический сдвиг влево»)

   ```
   result <<= 1;           //  вывод
   // 48  00110000 => 01100000   96
   // 49  00110001 => 01100010   98
   ```
2. Арифметический сдвиг влево с дополнением единицей.

   ```
   result = с << 1;  result++;   
   // 48  00110000 => 01100001   97
   // 49  00110001 => 01100011   99
   ```
3. Арифметический сдвиг влево с расширением по биту чётности.

   ```
   result = с << 1;  result += c - '0' /* даёт фактически 0 или 1*/;
   // 48  00110000 => 01100000  96 как в 1
   // 49  00110001 => 01100011  99 как в 2
   ```

   Не могу сказать зачем такой сдвиг нужен, обычно используется расширение по знаковому биту (чтоб после сдвига сохранился знак). Этот вид сдвига может использоваться, чтоб сохранить знак в числе, в котором биты расположены «задом наперёд».

   Сдвиг бывает [арифметический/циклический] [влево/вправо] [(с дополнением 0)/ с дополнением 1 / с расширением по биту чётности / с расширением по знаковому биту / с дополнением переноса (флага СF)].

UPD: я немного ошибся, не увидел цикл. Из с берётся один бит, и ложится в сдвинутый result, который изначально 0. Поэтом код как раз переводит из двоичной системы. Обычно для проверки бита используют `c & 1`, но если нужно проверить первый бит то можно `с-'0'`, но я бы выбрал первое, т.к. оно более очевидно что получится.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья https://teccxx.neocities.org/mx1/integer_bitwise.html

Comment: наверное из двоичной, а не в двоичную?

Comment: @nick_n_a Да статья что надо, спасибо!